# Can my eyes adjust instantly to my friend's glasses?

Tags: human-biology, vision

My eyesight is pretty much perfect, but I noticed that whenever I try any of my friends glasses, from really thin to extremely thick, my eyes seem to adjust to them within seconds and let me see perfectly fine. Is this weird or abnormal, I was just really curious.

Comment: how 'strong' are the glasses? i.e. how many diopters? If they are small correctional glasses the distortion of the image to you may be minimal. Thick glasses expectedly are stronger, but just to verify.

Comment: @WYSIWYG the question is understandable. Please, take a look on the answer.

Comment: @rg255 the question is understandable. Please, take a look on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The phenomenon you described as "my eyes seem to adjust" is a particular case of accommodation - adjustment of the [dioptric power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dioptric_correction) of the crystalline lens to the object's distance.

When you place a lens before your eye, any object seen through this lens will initially appear at a different distance (and of different size of course) and will be blurred at different degrees (i.e out of focus). Thus, to overcome this discrepancy the eye must accommodate.

Now, the amplitude of accommodation is the maximal power which can be added to the current power of the crystalline lens. The younger the subject, the higher amplitude of accommodation he/she has:

[image]

Thus, if one young [emmetropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emmetropia) person (person 1) wears some other person's [myopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myopia) glasses (person 2) with a concave lens with minus power to lessen the actual "overpower" of the optic system, and this power does not have the refractive error of person 1's has (less myopia if they have any "hidden" myopia), the eye must accommodate, i.e. by increasing the convexity of the crystalline lens. If the amplitude of accommodation is much higher than the glasses in question, person 1 will easily adjust to these glasses by elimination of dioptric discrepancy.

Thus, Sherlock Holmes could deduce the following:

You are a young person (under the age of 30) with a high amplitude of accommodation.

You have a lot of "four-eyed" friends suffering from myopia.

From these facts the fiction writer could assume even your nationality (developed country) and level of close work (reading books, using computers) your friends are doing but - let's leave those assumptions to writers! :)